# System.Threading.Timer TimerCallback delegate with parameters?

Tags: c#, timer

I need to pass the following `int dldnow` to sendData static method / delegate.

```
public int dldnow;
Timer timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(sendData), null, 1000*30, 1000*30);

public static void sendData(object obj)
{
  string imageCount = (string)dldnow;
  string imageCountJson = wc.DownloadString("http://*********/u.php?count=" + imageCount);
}
```

Comment: As stated in the answer, simply put in `dldnow` as the parameter `state` (where you write `null` now). Another thing: You don't _have to_ write `new TimerCallback(sendData)` in full. Since C# 2 you can just write `sendData` (this is called method group conversion).

Comment: Right version with parameter refreshing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931850/timer-callback-delegate-doesnt-get-the-refreshed-value-from-parameter-on-every

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to pass it once, use a second constructor parameter:

```
System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(sendData), dldnow, 1000*30, 1000*30);
```

If you want to access it regularly, you can make a static volatile field:

```
public static volatile int dldnow;
```

(volatile is need so that it would be always up to date when accessed from multiple threads)