# Timer callback delegate doesn't get the refreshed value from parameter on every run

Tags: c#

I now have the following code. It is working otherwise but the `picturesDownloaded` doesn't update. In those 5 seconds sendData isn't called `picturesDownloaded` gets another value. How to refresh it everytime the timer runs? So that `obj.ToString()` will be the right value.

On one point `picturesDownloaded` gets value "11" but `object obj` still has value "0".

```
public static volatile string picturesDownloaded = "0";
System.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer(sendData, picturesDownloaded, 1000 * 5, 1000 * 5);

public static void sendData(object obj)
{
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    string imageCountJson = wc.DownloadString("http://******/u.php?count=" + obj.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static volatile string picturesDownloaded = "0";
System.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer(sendData, new Func<string>(() => picturesDownloaded), 1000 * 5, 1000 * 5);

public static void sendData(object obj)
{
    var value = ((Func<string>)obj)();
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    string imageCountJson = wc.DownloadString("http://******/u.php?count=" + value);
}
```

The problem is that when you create the timer, you pass the constructor a reference to the string `"0"`.  When you update the value of `picturesDownloaded`, it doesn't change the value of the object that was passed to the `Timer` constructor.

This can be remedied by providing an anonymous method to the `Timer` constructor that can retrieve the updated value of `picturesDownloaded`, and then calling that method in the callback.

Comment: I now get an error: Error 1 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: Would it be possible to give that method 3 parameters instead of one (picturesDownloaded). Or an array?

Comment: I would wrap whatever parameters you need in a single object, and make the `Func` return that object.